# How to kill Thread on exit?

Tags: c#, winforms

A button on the parent form is used to start the thread.
If the parent form is closed in the development environment the thread keeps running in the background preventing edits to the source code on a 64 bit Windows 7 platform.
The thread has to be killed by Menu > Debug > Stop Debugging.
What is the proper way to programmatically kill the thread when the parent Form is closed?

```
private void buttonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Main.MyThread);
    t.Start();
}

private static void MyThread()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you want the app to exit when the main thread has finished, you can just make the new thread a background thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Main.MyThread);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

Basically the process will exit when all the *foreground* threads have exited.

Note that this could be bad news if the background thread is writing a file when the form is closed, or something similar...

Comment: I can't believe I always stored a stack of threads on the main thread and iterate through it to close them all.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. BTW: just getting started in your book.

Comment: @JackN: Glad to help. Hope you enjoy the book :)

Comment: @Bruno manually stopping your thread is still usually a good idea, since that way you can stop them gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.Exit(0)` terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code. It is more generally used in console applications.

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```