# How to stop a thread when application is closed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am spawning a thread in the Form_load method and would like to close this thread when the application is closed.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          new Thread(() =>
            {             
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 6101.
                Int32 port = 6101;
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (isServerRun)
                {
               //     Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
             //       Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
             

                        ReceiveCommand(data);

                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }

                MessageBox.Show("STOPPING");
                server.Stop();

            }
            catch (SocketException ett)
            {
                
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }


        }).Start();
    }

        }
```

For that i am setting a  variable to false and the loop in the spawned function should exit.

```
 private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {         
            isServerRun = false;  // with isServerRun as false the while
        }
```

loop should quit in the spawned thread function.

But still the Spawned thread does not quit

Comment: After `isServerRun` loop is terminated, the thread is still waiting for `Console.Read()`, thus it doesn't end.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang i have updated my code and it still does not stop after removing Console.Read()

Comment: Did `MessageBox.Show("STOPPING");` show up?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang no the message did not pop up.

Comment: Related: [How to kill Thread on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062527/how-to-kill-thread-on-exit)

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you're still blocking on `AcceptTcpClient`. It seems like the real solution here would be to use the asynchronous methods (i.e. BeginAcceptTcpClient, EndAcceptTcpClient, etc.) of `TcpListener` rather than explicitly running it in a thread. If you want to keep the code as it is, you could follow the advice in the question Theodor linked, or you could take a reference to the thread and use `myThreadReference.Abort();`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort) is no longer supported in .NET (.NET Core and later). See [Alternative option to Thread.Abort()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66943) or [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11369).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Right you are. I did look at the .NET 6 docs, but it seems you actually have to scroll down to a specific overload's documentation to see that it's actually not supported anymore. You'd think they would display that a little bit more prominently. Oh well. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
static bool isCancellation = false;
static object gateway = new object();

lock (gateway)
{
    isCancellation = true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Thread.SpinWait(5000000);

    lock (gateway)
    {
        if (isCancellation)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At StackOverflow we appreciate the supporting text as much as the working solution proposals. Please add some description why do you think your proposed solution could help to solve OP's problem.